# Backbone save ? appears in the URL

Tags: php, backbone.js, save

when i do a save an ? sign appears in the URL, before the #

```
http://localhost:8000/html/WebChecker/www/?#signin
```

The code of the save is the next

```
signin : function(){
        var logi = document.forms['signin']['name'].value;
        var mail = document.forms['signin']['email'].value;
        var passwd = document.forms['signin']['pass'].value;
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(passwd).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
        var tkn=Math.random(9) * 123123123;
        var user = new User({'login' : logi, 'email' : mail, 'pass' : hash, 'token': tkn.toString(), 'recovery' : null, 'img': 'default.png'});
        //var user = new User({'user' : logi, 'pass' : hash});
        user.save({},{
            wait : true,
            success : function(response){
                alert("OK");
                alert(response.res);
                Backbone.history.navigate("", {trigger: true});
            },
            error : function(options){
                alert('ERROR');
                Backbone.history.navigate("#signin", {trigger: true});
            }
        });
```

And the php post function is:

```
try{
        $pdo = conectar();
        $insertar = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user (login, email, pass, name, token, recovery, img) VALUES (:login, :email, :pass, :name, :token, :recovery, :img ); ');
        $insertar->bindParam(':login', $data->login);
        $insertar->bindParam(':email', $data->email);
        $insertar->bindParam(':pass', $data->pass);
        $insertar->bindParam(':name', $data->login); 
        $insertar->bindParam(':token', $data->token);
        $insertar->bindParam(':recovery', $data->recovery);
        $insertar->bindParam(':img', $data->img);
        $insertar->execute();
        $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        echo "{'res' : 'ok', 'id' : ".$id."}";
        $pdo = null;
        //$pdo = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
```

If anybody knows the reason...

Thank you

Comment: Anything after a question mark "?" is considered after the URI, and is then in fact part of the query string. I don't know if that helps or not, because you haven't fully explained your question. Please see this guide on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My guess is you aren't calling `preventDefault` on the form event. But without seeing the rest of code where you call `user.save` it's hard to tell.

Comment: You try doing `Backbone.history.navigate("signin", {trigger: true});` without the #? Or you can add the full url path minus the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Marc Greenstock, that was the answer. 
event.preventDefault makes the event wait (I think thats how preventDefault works).

Thank you so much!